# Google charts api after ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-visualization

I've got a problem with the visualization of data with google's charts api after an ajax call.

First I made an ajax call and fetched a json object. After that I want to extract some data out of the json and draw a gauge chart. Getting the json and extracting the data works fine, but when I try to load the chart, the body gets removed and I get a blank/white screen. Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong? I also tried to hard code values for the chart instead of taking the json values (but kept the ajax call before loading the chart), but it didn't work neither.

```
function loadStats(){
    var http = getRequestObject();
    var city = "berlin";
    http.open("GET", "getTwitterSentiments.php?city="+city, true);
    http.onreadystatechange=function() {
        getStatistic(http)
    };
    http.send(null);
}

function getStatistic(request) {
    if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200)) {
        var data = request.responseText;
        var JSONStats = eval("(" + data + ")");
        loadGauge(JSONStats.sentiment_index);
    }

function loadGauge(sentiment){
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge);
    function drawGauge() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Label', 'Value'],
            ['Test', sentiment]     
        ]);

        var options = {
            width: 100, 
            height: 100,
            redFrom: 0, 
            redTo: 45,
            yellowFrom: 45,
            yellowTo: 55,
            greenFrom: 55, 
            greenTo: 100,
            minorTicks: 10
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('testgchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have not marked any answer as correct, how did you solve the problem? I am also stuck into this.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the callback feature of `google.load()` function.

For instance, for your code, try the following:

```
function loadGauge(sentiment){
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['gauge'], 'callback': drawGauge});

}

function drawGauge(){
...
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

For more information, check the 'Dynamic loading' section of `Google Loader Developer Guide`:
https://developers.google.com/loader/#Dynamic

If i understand correctly, calling loadGauge() multiple times will **not** cause multiple trips to Google servers to load the required APIs, but just once.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your element `testgchart` is not load in the DOM yet, your code should work.

I made an example from your code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
    function loadGauge(val){
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge);
        function drawGauge() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Label', 'Value'],
              ['Test', val],
            ]);

            var options = {
                width: 100, 
                height: 100,
                redFrom: 0, 
                redTo: 45,
                yellowFrom: 45,
                yellowTo: 55,
                greenFrom: 55, 
                greenTo: 100,
                minorTicks: 10
            };


            var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('average'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="average"></div>
    <script>loadGauge(99)</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work if you delete this line `<script>loadGauge(99)</script>` and replace the body tag with `<body onload="loadGauge(99)">`. Your probably doing something similar.

If your sure the element `testgchart` is present then put a log in `loadGauge` and tell me if it really get called by `getStatistic`.